# Javascript creates too many input elements

Tags: javascript, dom

Can't quite figure this out. In Firefox, (only tested it in Firefox), this code creates 8 inputs and 8 buttons. I think it should only create one. Need some help on this one.

```
var replacefiles = function(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var length = inputs.length // prevent infinite loop
    for (var x = 0; x < length; x++){
        var type = inputs[x].getAttribute('type');
        if (type === 'file'){
            var file = inputs[x];
            var parent = file.parentNode;
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            var button = document.createElement('button');
            parent.insertBefore(input, file);
            parent.insertBefore(button, file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without your HTML, we can't tell. There may very well be 8 on the page already.

Comment: show surrounding html with the input.

Comment: You should alos move "var type" declartion out of the for loop. There's not need to declare this variable everytime. Move it up and just set type in the for statement. This also goes for every variable in your if statement that's in your for loop.

Comment: @MattMoore: That won't make any difference.

Comment: @Slaks: I didn't intend it as an answer, its just good coding practice.

Comment: @MattMoore: I disagree.  If it's only used inside the loop, it should be declared inside the loop (even though JS doesn't have block scope)

Comment: Agree with SLaks! I hate when people declare all variables at the top of a function, even though it's only used in a tiny block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a live view of the results.

When you insert a new `<input>` before the current one, the current gets shifted over, so `inputs[i + 1]` now points to the same `<input type="file">`.

You need to copy the results into a normal array by writing

```
inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs);
```